# Connection poolling with couchbase server

Tags: couchbase

i want to use multiple connection to the couchbase server. Please suggest if any connection pool library available for libcouchbase client.

Comment: This [link](http://trondn.blogspot.com/2012/01/so-how-do-i-use-this-libcouchbase.html) contains some advices about pooling connections. May be it will help.

Comment: the link is not given any information regarding pool of connection. It just giving how to design simple example. Please suggest if you know how to create pool of connection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't aware of such libraries, but it shouldn't be hard to write your own. For example, we do pooling in our pillowfight utility:

https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/blob/master/tools/cbc-pillowfight.cc#L251

It isn't absolutely portable, because it is relying on pthreads, though.

Comment: Thanks avsej. I got some idea from that, But I want to develop pool in c.It will be great if  you have any c example.